# Ошибка при подключении шрифтов

Tags: css, шрифты

Нужно подключить шрифты к странице, но они не подключаются и консоль гугла также ругается: **'GET file:///C:/Users/.../GamePage/style/font/DINPro-Black.otf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND'**
Что интересно именно этот шрифт(DINPro-Black) подключился, т.е. он работает в то время как 2 других, которые пытаюсь подключить ни в какую не хотят отображаться как нужно (по внешнему виду похоже на sans-serif).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@font-face {
font-family: DINPro Black;
src: url(font/DINPro-Black.otf);

font-family: Open Sans Light;
src: url('font/OpenSans-Light.ttf'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Light.otf');

font-family: Open Sans ExtraBold;
src: url('font/OpenSans-Extrabold.ttf'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Extrabold.otf'),
     url('font/opensans-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
```

}

P.S. Шрифты скачал с шрифтобелки.

Comment: в консоли же явно пишется ошибка. Не найдено. Проверяй путь к файлам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DINPro Black;
    src: url(../font/DINPro-Black.otf);

    font-family: Open Sans Light;
    src: url('../font/OpenSans-Light.ttf'),
         url('../font/OpenSans-Light.otf');

    font-family: Open Sans ExtraBold;
    src: url('../font/OpenSans-Extrabold.ttf'),
         url('../font/OpenSans-Extrabold.otf'),
         url('../font/opensans-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
```